# unable to connect to FTP using file zilla

Tags: ftp

I am trying to connect to my server using FTP but every time I try to connect I get the below error.

Status:     Resolving address of ftp.bhuumi.com
Status:     Connecting to 160.153.245.204:21...
Status:     Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status:     Initializing TLS...
Status:     Verifying certificate...
Status:     TLS connection established.
Status:     Logged in
Status:     Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (64,202,160,248,195,178)
Command:    MLSD
Error:      The data connection could not be established: ETIMEDOUT - Connection attempt timed out

I have tried changing encryption to only use plain FTP but still getting the sam error

Answer (score 0):

Once, Try with SFTP. For SSH select 22 port, mine got connected.

[image]